# Convert PHP code (proc_open) to Python (Popen)

Tags: php, python, subprocess

I'm trying to convert this piece of PHP code to Python. I've figured out how to do the `crc32b` hash but I'm stuck on `proc_open()`. Could you help me out?

What I want is to get the value of `$pipeOutput` in Python code.

**PHP**

```
$hashedData = strrev(hash("crc32b", $data, true)) . $data;
$xzBinary = trim(`which xz`);
$xzProcess = proc_open("$xzBinary '--format=raw' '--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB' '-c' '-'", [
    0 => [
        "pipe",
        "r"
    ],
    1 => [
        "pipe",
        "w"
    ]
], $xzProcessPipes);
fwrite($xzProcessPipes[0], $hashedData);
fclose($xzProcessPipes[0]);
$pipeOutput = stream_get_contents($xzProcessPipes[1]);
fclose($xzProcessPipes[1]);
proc_close($xzProcess);
```

**Python**

```
import zlib
from subprocess import Popen


def crc32b(x):
    h = zlib.crc32(x)
    x='%08X' % (h & 0xffffffff,)
    return x.lower()

data = 'some_data'

hashed_data = crc32b(data)[::-1]+data #strrev(hash("crc32b", $data, true)) . $data;
xz_binary = '//usr/bin/xz'
r = Popen([xz_binary, "--format=raw",'--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB','-c','-'])
```

**EDIT**

```
hashed_data = crc32b(data)[::-1]+data
xz_binary = '//usr/bin/xz'
p = Popen([xz_binary, "--format=raw",'--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB','-c','-'],stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

p.communicate()
stdout_file = p.stdout
stdin_file = p.stdin
stdin_file.write(hashed_data)
```

says that `stdin_file` is closed but I'm not sure if this is what I should do

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Use [`r.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) and [`r.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout)?

Comment: Don't know how. Especially this part of the command: 0 => [
        "pipe",
        "r"
    ],
    1 => [
        "pipe",
        "w"
    ]
], $xzProcessPipes);

Comment: It seems to be stdin and stdout

Comment: Did you write the PHP code yourself? Why aren't you certain what it does?

Comment: It is not my code but the licence allows me to do anything with the code. I want to convert it to python.

Comment: Try interacting with the pipes after redirecting stdin / stdout in the `Popen` constructor, then calling `r.communicate()`.